# Property does not exist on type / can't be used as index type

Tags: arrays, typescript

I want to have an object that can contain strings in its root, and an array of strings in the arrayValues object. This is a config object that will be used in an app.

This object and its keys will be dynamic (defined via user state values) so I have no way of specifying types based on the specific key name.

I will be adding arrays to "arrayValues" from one part of my app, and strings to "filters" from another part of the app.

However I'm getting errors when accessing object properties:
[TS PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiBLANjYUDOAyjAIa4AqyqAvHAN4BQccAZtrgQFxPNwA+9Hr14koUEogBqJLAFdg+TvTgB6FXADGJAHZwI2rIjgkwKUXu0bUGXWxx58egEYArYBphDhvANoBrYEQlfBgoGwBzAF0lAEExCQAeELDtcIA+L2EAX0y4HOEBOjh-QODQiOi4ZIi8hhyGDX0QuFASAFswLGAlTHsCYjJgShQ4WkZmOw5FQWFRcSkZeWnx73wdABMAdwwNAAsFJR8Acl32o4AaOCO94AVgI8jz3LbsP3xTgOnjvYgNC6unDogQ8ntlQbxxNp1hA2sQUuElCdgFgsBALjwsk96q0Ol0AHSTBx4uYSaRyBR4tZQ7Y3fAE9h4AAUjIwuDaZXhAEpRmk4KzgG04ABCai0E5nbkMNRwQAy5HAAApQCAoWBGI5UrY7fb4I5waEKODaCDwUAYZr6BBUK7VVL8ZQlIJVcqpSo28I+SIAbjyRzxUvUcsVyrwSGtGxp2t1+scRpNIDN8AtSBG6ud4SODAaTXgboA0oFRlcXlg3h8FBmcZ1gPS+nSSQtyfgfHnApEaxxmfz2U6uTy+WzhaKrj8-pLpXKAKJdNrAbTwDC4naswxwU6OHRXHSIXXJ1BOdwkWT4VCgMBQBT4DAWiAsS0pgBExdLJE+991Wm0R3g+7gR+A6wQCA+ShUA71QVN4TtIoHQ5CpYNSD1vSyX1-VlBUlRVUMjifd4X3LPUIANWMWnjc1dF3a00yg4oAkdN1XTTRCfUzSt8UJAg8UhaFYSosUnEQe5UMDDCQzVLiYThCIo0ImNjRIhMLDAq4inrZYaNKHs4M0hCvTyJDqJg7Song8IkJQ8d0ODVUrnEnj4Wkoi5NNMilKOFT4kQNTDPokymKyJCgA)

```
export type FiltersStateType = {
  filters:
    | {
        arrayValues: { // note: this should only appear once in filters object
          [key: string]: Array<string>
        }
      }
    | { [key: string]: string }
}

const example: FiltersStateType = {
  filters: {
    arrayValues: {
      sandwiches: ['ham', 'cheese'],
      milkshakes: ['choc', 'banana'],
    },
    randomString: 'hello',
  },
}

example.filters.arrayValues.sandwiches.filter((item: string) => item !== 'ham') 
// ❌ Property 'sandwiches' does not exist on type 'string | { [key: string]: string[]; }'.
// ❌ Property 'sandwiches' does not exist on type 'string'

const stringKey = 'milkshakes'
example.filters.arrayValues[stringKey].filter((item: string) => item !== 'choc') 
// ❌ Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"milkshakes"' can't be used to index type 'string | { [key: string]: string[]; }'.
// ❌ Property 'milkshakes' does not exist on type 'string | { [key: string]: string[]; }'

example.filters.randomString = 'bye'
// ❌ Property 'randomString' does not exist on type '{ arrays: { [key: string]: string[]; }; } | { [key: string]: string; }'.
// ❌ Property 'randomString' does not exist on type '{ arrays: { [key: string]: string[]; }; }
```

I expected TypeScript to understand the types found in these objects as I've specified them in FiltersStateType.

Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: "*I expected TypeScript to understand the types found in these objects as I've specified them in FiltersStateType*" and it does that. However, your type might or might not have `sandwiches`. Hence why TS is stopping you because the usage might or might not be correct.

Comment: If it was a question of whether it existed or not, I would expect optional chaining to solve the problem - but it doesn't. Do you know how to solve it? Thanks! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the highlighted Union:

```
export type FiltersStateType = {
  filters:
    | {
        arrayValues: {
          [key: string]: Array<string>
        }
      }
    | { [key: string]: string } // this one
// ---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---
}
```

As you have specified `{ [key: string]: string }` in the union, the below object stands valid:

```js
const example: FiltersStateType = {
  filters: {
    arrayValues: 'hello',
  },
}
```

TypeScript is unable to enforce the shape of the value of `arrayValues` key, as `{ [key: string]: string }` itself means any key can have value of string. Ideally, you must change the structure of your type definitions something like this:

```
// this is just an example, you should
// restructure as per your requirements 
type FiltersStateType = {
  filters: { [key: string]: string },
  arrayValues: { [key: string]: Array<string> }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Super helpful! Marked as answer! 

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your `FiltersStateType` type like this:

```js
type FiltersStateType = {
  filters: {
    [key: string]: string | {[key: string]: string[]};
    arrayValues: { // can only appear once in filters object
      [key: string]: string[];
    }
  }
}

const example: FiltersStateType = {
  filters: {
    arrayValues: {
      sandwiches: ['ham', 'cheese'],
      milkshakes: ['choc', 'banana'],
    },
    randomString: 'hello',
  },
}

example.filters.arrayValues.sandwiches = example.filters.arrayValues.sandwiches.filter((item: string) => item !== 'ham');
console.log(example.filters.arrayValues.sandwiches);

const stringKey = 'milkshakes'
example.filters.arrayValues[stringKey] = example.filters.arrayValues[stringKey].filter((item: string) => item !== 'choc');
console.log(example.filters.arrayValues[stringKey]);

example.filters.randomString = 'bye';
console.log(example.filters.randomString);
```

Comment: Interesting! So with "[key: string]: string | {[key: string]: string[]};" in the FiltersStateType does the second part of the union type allow the arrayValues object? Why can't that line just be "[key: string]: string"? 
Currently it would mean I could add other objects which could have the same type as arrayValues...which I don't need.
Thanks again mate! 

Comment: Yes, you are right other properties also will be able to accept another type! But you can not write exception for one property in type. So the best way which you should use is @VinaySharma answer

Comment: Your solution is just a hack to eliminate the error, but it doesn’t prevent other keys from having the shape of `arrayValues`.

Comment: @VinaySharma I know and I wrote about it

Comment: @EzioMercer yes I did notice that but if your answer doesn’t really "answer" it should be avoided to write because it doesn’t help future readers and instead just deviates them into investing their time into an incomplete solution :)